# How to disable NuGet package restore and bring in packages locally?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

How do I get NuGet to regenerate/create the 'packages' folder that contains all of the .dlls *local* to an `ASP.NET` project? I know this goes against conventional use of 'Enable package restore' but its a prerequisite and out of scope for this conversation.

Unfortunately I already went down the path of enabling the restore before it was stated we could not use it. Now I need those packages regenerated locally and I can't seem to figure out how it's done. There are 1,000 documents on how to *delete* the packages and enable NuGet package restore but nothing on how to go back to having a 'packages' folder per solution. I actually have to check in that package to TFS and have everything available for the solution at build.

I've already disabled the 'Enable NuGet Package Restore' and rebuilt, but the dependencies are not being brought in locally anywhere I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you originally had the MSBuild based package restore enabled for your solution, you have "disabled" it, and now you want to restore the packages and add them to version control.

If you have a recent version of NuGet installed, 2.7 or above should do, then Visual Studio should restore the packages automatically when you build your solution.

Now if you have a recent version of NuGet and Visual Studio is not restoring the packages when you build then one possibility is that you still have the .nuget/NuGet.targets file in your solution. If this file still exists then Visual Studio assumes you are using the MSBuild based package restore and will not restore the packages when you build.

Another way to restore the packages is to download [NuGet.exe](https://nuget.codeplex.com/releases) and run:

```
NuGet.exe restore YourSolution.sln
```

Also there are [some instructions on NuGet's web site](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) about how to migrate from the MSBuild based package restore and move to the newer automatic package restore. One thing in this migration guide that may also affect TFS is the disableSourceControlIntegration setting which is in the NuGet.config file. You will probably want to remove that setting if not the .nuget/NuGet.config file itself.

Comment: turns out your answer combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270597/prevent-nuget-restore-package-in-debug-builds-only/9642631#9642631 led me to the solution. One thing I was mistaken on was the *packages* folder existed all along. I just forgot it's not visible from Solution Explorer, but rather alongside the solution in Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Tools->Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings

Package Manager - General

please unchecked the check box (Allow Auto Download...)
vs 2.13 by Default it will be enabled .
vs 2012 its disabled by default

Answer (score -1):

You can select your reference, press F4 and set the Copy Local property to True.
[image]